# Find local maximum

Tags: peak-detection

What instruction could I use to obtain the local maximum point of the red circle in the graph?
I tried using the $FindMaximum$ instruction, but couldn't get the desired result.

[image]

The curve generation code is as follows:

```
dt = 0.00006;
tend = 0.08;
sol = DSolve[{l il'[t] == vl[t], c vc'[t] == ic[t], 
    ir[t] == -ic[t] + il[t], vl[t] == 24 - vc[t], vr[t] == vc[t], 
    vr[t] == r ir[t], il[0] == 0, vc[0] == 0}, {ir[t], il[t], ic[t], 
    vr[t], vl[t], vc[t]}, t];
{il[t_], vc[t_]} = {il[t], vc[t]} /. sol[[1]];
pars1 = {r -> 22, l -> 1/5, c -> 1/10000};
a = Evaluate[vc[t] /. pars1];
dvc = D[a, t];
Subscript[dvc, n + 1] = ReplaceAll[dvc, t -> t + dt];
vcerror = Abs[-1/2*dt*(Subscript[dvc, n + 1] - dvc)];
Plot[{vcerror}, {t, 0, tend}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "vc[t]/v"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"vcerror"}, PlotStyle -> {Green}, PlotRange -> All]
NMaximize[{vcerror, 0 <= t <= tend}, t]
```

Comment: Try e.g.: `NMaximize[{vcerror, 0.01 < t < 0.02}, t]`

Comment: Thank you! If I don't need to change the range to obtain all the extreme values that appear, it would be great haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NMaximize` tries to find a global maximum. Because of this reason the interval should be reduced up to

```
Plot[{vcerror}, {t, 0.005, tend}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "vc[t]/v"}, 
PlotLegends -> {"vcerror"}, PlotStyle -> {Green}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

in order to obtain the local maximum

```
NMaximize[{vcerror, 0.005 <= t <= 0.02}, t, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> `{0.000286032,{t->0.00886578}}`

Addition. In order to find some critical points,  one may do

```
vcerror = RealAbs[-1/2*dt*(Subscript[dvc, n + 1] - dvc)];
```

(`Abs` is not differentiable, so the one is replaced by `RealAbs`.)

and then

```
NSolve[D[vcerror, t] == 0 && t >= 0 && t <= 0.05]
```

> `{{t -> 0.00441792}, {t -> 0.00886578}}`

The former is the local minimum and the latter is the local maximum.

Comment: Hello sir, is there an instruction that can directly obtain the local maximum values of all occurrences?

Comment: Have you tried setting the first derivative to zero?

Comment: @banone Yes, that's a good idea. Thank you for your inspiration.